# sql get top 10 groups by user points

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a users table

```
id, name, points, group_id
```

and a groups table

```
id, name
```

and I would like to get the TOP 10 groups based on the sum of the points of their users:

```
select top 10 [groups].[name], [groups].[id], SUM(users.points) as points
    from [groups] inner join [users] on [groups].[id] = [users].[group_id] 
    group by [groups].[id], [groups].[name], [points] 
    order by [points] desc
```

Unfortunately I get multiple entries for the same group for each user that it has.

Comment: Remove the `points` from group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track:

```
select top 10 g.name, g.id, SUM(u.points) as sum_points
from groups g inner join
     users u
     on g.id = u.group_id
group by g.name, g.id
order by sum_points desc;
```

Notes:

- The big difference is removing `points` from the `group by`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The alias for the `SUM()` is *different* from the name of the column.  This prevents confusion, particularly in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Top 10 in each group of `[groups].[id], [groups].[name]`

```
With Cte AS
(        
  select
         [groups].[name], 
         [groups].[id], 
         SUM(users.points) as points,
         Dense_Rank() Over (Partition By [groups].[id], [groups].[name] Order by SUM(users.points) Desc) as rank
  from [groups] inner join [users] on [groups].[id] = [users].[group_id] 
 )
Select [name],[id],[points] from Cte where rank<=10
```

For Top 10 in all records remove [point] from group by

```
select top 10 [groups].[name], 
              [groups].[id], 
              SUM(users.points) as points
from [groups] inner join [users] on [groups].[id] = [users].[group_id] 
group by [groups].[id], [groups].[name], [points] 
order by [points] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Points from Group By and Order by SUM(Points)

```
select top 10 [groups].[name], [groups].[id], SUM(users.points) as points
    from [groups] inner join [users] on [groups].[id] = [users].[group_id] 
    group by [groups].[id], [groups].[name]
    order by SUM(users.points) desc
```